# Why am I getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with my custom font array?

Tags: java, fonts, java-2d

I'm making a game for [#towerjam](https://jams.gamejolt.com/towerjam), and I need render some fonts I made. Here is the code I'm using.

```
public static void render(String msg, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    msg.toUpperCase();
    char[] msgArray = msg.toCharArray();
    for (char c : msgArray) {
        System.out.println();
        g.drawImage(letters[c-65], x, y, Tile.DRAW_SIZE, Tile.DRAW_SIZE, null);
        x+=Tile.DRAW_SIZE;
    }
}
```

The array `letters` is a array of BufferedImages cropped from my spritesheet. Right now its giving me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace? How many and what elements does `letters` array it contain? For what value of `c` you are getting this exception (something tells me it is character outside of `A-Z` range assuming that these characters ware stored in `letters` array)?

Comment: The `letters` array is all the uppercase letters' sprites I made. That would be 26. `c` has a value of the last letter in the `String` although nothing shows up.

Comment: It sounds like you've got a solution for "custom fonts" - your question is actually "Why the error"? SUGGESTION: 1) Fire up your favorite debugger in your favorite IDE (e.g. Eclipse), 2) Invoke the error, look at the traceback.  Get the line#..  It's probably `g.drawImage()`.  3) Set a breakpoint at that line. 4) Invoke the error again. You might hit the bkpt multiple times before then. 5) Inspect the variables (e.g. `c`).  Compare it with the length of your array (e.g. `letters`).  6) Voila!  At that point, you should be able to resolve the problem :)  GUESS: "c" is "out of bounds" ;)

Comment: `Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52` is what I get when the String is this: `tesa`.  `c` has the value of `t`

Comment: Q: Is your array `"A-Z" `.. or `"a-z"`?  Two completely different ranges :)  Look at [String.toUpperCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: A: Yes I already had the String uppercased. They are all A-Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java (like in many other languages) so since `msg.toUpperCase();` can't edit original string it creates new one with upper case characters and *returns it*.

If you want to have this returned string stored in `msg` simply reassign it back to `msg`:

```
msg = msg.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Here's the text being rendered in top right corner: [image](http://ibin.co/2SE7yvulk4lr)